# How to optimise a strictly increasing stack based list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, stack

So I am trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures
Basically given an array [30,40,50,60]
we need to return the indices of the next increasing value
so output would be [1,1,1,0]
My algorithm is to

1. while end !=0 read from the array
2. if last element add 0 to output and stack
3. Else if temperature[end] > stack top add to stack and add stack top to be the temperature difference.
4. If temperature[end] <= stack top then we pop every element until this condition breaks and update the stack top and output.

I keep getting a time limit exceeded here, My understanding here is that the complexity is O(N). I am not sure how to optimise it further.

```
def dailyTemperatures(self, temperatures: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        output = []
        r = len(temperatures) - 1
        stack = []
        while r >= 0:
            if r == len(temperatures) - 1:
                stack.append(r)
                output.insert(0, 0)
            else:
                if temperatures[stack[-1]] > temperatures[r]:
                    output.insert(0, stack[-1]-r)
                    stack.append(r)
                else:
                    while stack and temperatures[stack[-1]] <= temperatures[r]:
                        stack.pop()
                    if len(stack) == 0:
                        output.insert(0, 0)
                        stack.append(r)
                    else:
                        output.insert(0, stack[-1]-r)
                        stack.append((r))

            r -= 1
        return output
```

Answer (score 1):

An efficient implementation of a slow algorithm will still scale slowly.  Optimizing the stack won't change the big-O.  But I'll outline an idea using a different data structure for you to figure out.

In example1 of the problem you start with the array `[73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73]`.  Let's arrange this in terms of maxes of ranges like so:

```
x = [
    [73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73],
    [   74,   75,   72,   76],
    [         75,         76],
    [                     76],
]
```

In other words `x[i][j]` gives the max of all elements from `j * 2**i` to `(j+1) * 2**i - 1`.

Now to find the first rise after `k` we go "forward and down" until we find a block with a larger (or 0 if there is none) and then "up and forward" until we find where it is.  Where:

while going forward and down at (i, j):
if j is even:
if j not at end of x[i]:
move to (i, j+1) then test
else:
answer is 0
else:
move to (i+1, j//2 + 1) then test

while going up and forward at (i, j) with 0 < i:
if answer in range for (i-1, j+j):
move to (i-1, j+j)
else:
move to (i-1, j+j+1)

For example if `k` was `2` we would do this.

```
start at (0, 2)
go f&d to (0, 3), check if 75 < x[0][3] (ie 71), stay f&d
go f&d to (1, 2), check if 75 < x[1][2] (ie 72), stay f&d
go f&d to (1, 3), check if 75 < x[1][3] (ie 76), switch to u&f
check if 75 < x[0][6] (ie 76) go u&f to (0, 6)
```

And now we know that the next one is at position 6.  So we get `6 - 2 == 4` there.

What is the performance?  The whole data structure is `O(n)` to build. Each lookup is at worst `O(log(n))`.  So doing the `n` checks is at worst `O(n log(n))`.  Which should be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

After considerable testing, your answer IS linear.  (And therefore better than what I suggested before.) However in order to meet their time limit you need to microptimize everything.  Meaning get rid of every unneeded `if`, make sure your comparisons are the fastest possible, etc.

I would definitely say that leetcode set the time limit too restrictively for the problem and language performance.

```
def dailyTemperatures(self, temperatures: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    if 0 == len(temperatures):
        return []
    output = [0]
    r = len(temperatures) - 1
    stack = [r]
    r -= 1
    while r >= 0:
        while len(stack) and temperatures[stack[-1]] <= temperatures[r]:
            stack.pop()
        if len(stack) == 0:
            output.append(0)
        else:
            output.append(stack[-1]-r)
        stack.append((r))
        r -= 1
    output.reverse()
    return output
```

Comment: uh it still hits the time limit exceeds error, I might just give up now :(

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is

```
def dailyTemperatures(self, temperatures):
    res = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(temperatures) - 1:
        j = i + 1
        while True:
            if j >= len(temperatures):
                res.append(0)
                break
            if temperatures[j] <= temperatures[i]:
                j += 1
            else:
                res.append(j - i)
                break
        i += 1
    res.append(0)
    return res
```

Comment: If you have `n` temperatures sorted descending, this algorithm will be `O(n^2)`. Which will give time exceeded.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution with smaller time complexity, as you always have to check if the next index is smaller or bigger, the only better solution was using enumerator and stack

Comment: I think that the complexity here is probably not better than my original solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: wont the complexity be n^2 here ?

Comment: @ahtashamnazeer There is definitely a better time complexity. My post answers how, though I deliberately avoided providing code for the challenge.

Comment: @btilly Agreed, isnt the time complexity on mine close to N though ? so better than your nlogn ?

Comment: @LeoBabyJacob Reading more carefully, your problem might be `output.insert(0, ...)`. That's a `O(n)` operation.  Try building output up with just `append` and then `return list(reversed(output))` to get the right order.

Comment: I did that tbh, it gave me a time limit exceed. Maybe I should use a dequeue right